# How to find the partial derivatives of a piecewise function given in Cartesian form?

Tags: complex-analysis

$$
f(z) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
           \frac{x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4}{x^2+y^2}+i\frac{4x^3y-4xy^3}{x^2+y^2}  & \quad  z \neq 0 \\
            0 & \quad z= 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

To determine if $f$ is complex-differentiable at $0$, I need to first find the partial derivatives of the real and imaginary parts of $f$. But how do I proceed? I'm stumped because the function is piecewise. I initially tried working from definition, but because $f$ is in Cartesian form, I got stuck, and then figured that it's necessary to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a function is ($\mathbb{R}$-)differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if you can find a linear map $A : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that :
$$f(x,y)=A(x,y) + o(\|(x,y)\|).$$

In particular if you can show that $f(x,y)=o(\|(x,y)\|)$ then $f$ is differentiable.
Bearing this in mind and using the useful inequality $xy \leq \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$, you should be able to conclude.

EDIT : note that if $z \neq 0$, then $f(z)=\frac{z^4}{|z|^2}$. That should tell you that $f$ is differentiable at 0 with zero derivative. (however $f$ is not complex-differentiable).

Comment: what is your definition of differentiability ? I just gave you mine. (the existence of partial derivatives is not sufficient in general for $f$ to be differentiable at a certain point). then I'm giving you a method : prove that $f(x,y)=\phi(x,y)\|(x,y\|$, where $\phi(x,y)$ tends to 0, and this will prove that $f$ is differentiable at 0, with derivative 0

Comment: I was going to find the partials, use Cauchy-Riemann, and then check for continuity. Sorry, I don't know about linear maps or the norm sybmbol you're using wrt complex analysis.

Comment: do you want to check for real differentiability or complex differentiability ? in the first case the Cauchy Riemann equations will not help you. By $\|(x,y)\|$ I mean $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: sorry i want to check for complex differntiability.

Comment: with my edit you should be able to prove that it is complex differentiable at 0. however is is not complex differentiable elsewhere.